ROS2 LiDAR topic not showing
I'm trying to implement a LiDAR sensor in my simulation. I've added the sensor and it seems to work in Gazebo but I can't see the topic showing in ros2 topic list or in Rviz.
Here is the topic list:
~/ros2_ws$ ros2 topic list
/clicked_point
/clock
/drone/bottom/camera_info
/drone/bottom/image_raw
/drone/cmd_vel
/drone/cmd_vel/statistics
/drone/data
/drone/dronevel_mode
/drone/dronevel_mode/statistics
/drone/front/camera_info
/drone/front/image_raw
/drone/gps/vel
/drone/gt_acc
/drone/gt_pose
/drone/gt_vel
/drone/imu
/drone/imu/out
/drone/imu/statistics
/drone/land
/drone/land/statistics
/drone/posctrl
/drone/posctrl/statistics
/drone/reset
/drone/reset/statistics
/drone/sonar
/drone/takeoff
/drone/takeoff/statistics
/goal_pose
/initialpose
/joint_states
/parameter_events
/performance_metrics
/robot_description
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
Here is my simulation that is being used.
Here is the XACRO and URDF (in this order) files that I've changed in order tot add the LiDAR:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="sjtu_drone"
  xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.477"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.1152" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1152" iyz="0" izz="0.218"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sjtu_drone_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0   0   0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sjtu_drone_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0   0   0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="sonar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="sonar_link" />
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="sonar_link"/>


  <joint name="front_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="front_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="front_cam_link"/>

  <joint name="bottom_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="bottom_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="bottom_cam_link"/>
  
  <!-- Link for LiDAR sensor -->
<link name="lidar_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.1"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<!-- Joint to attach LiDAR to the drone -->
<joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/> <!-- Aligned forward with a slight elevation -->
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="lidar_link"/>
</joint>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name='simple_drone' filename='libplugin_drone.so'>
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <rosNamespace>drone</rosNamespace>
      <imuTopic>imu</imuTopic>
      <rollpitchProportionalGain>10.0</rollpitchProportionalGain>
      <rollpitchDifferentialGain>5.0</rollpitchDifferentialGain>
      <rollpitchLimit>0.5</rollpitchLimit>
      <yawProportionalGain>2.0</yawProportionalGain>
      <yawDifferentialGain>1.0</yawDifferentialGain>
      <yawLimit>1.5</yawLimit>
      <velocityXYProportionalGain>5.0</velocityXYProportionalGain>
      <velocityXYDifferentialGain>2.3</velocityXYDifferentialGain>
      <velocityXYLimit>2</velocityXYLimit>
      <velocityZProportionalGain>5.0</velocityZProportionalGain>
      <velocityZIntegralGain>0.0</velocityZIntegralGain>
      <velocityZDifferentialGain>1.0</velocityZDifferentialGain>
      <velocityZLimit>-1</velocityZLimit>
      <positionXYProportionalGain>1.1</positionXYProportionalGain>
      <positionXYDifferentialGain>0.0</positionXYDifferentialGain>
      <positionXYIntegralGain>0.0</positionXYIntegralGain>
      <positionXYLimit>5</positionXYLimit>
      <positionZProportionalGain>1.0</positionZProportionalGain>
      <positionZDifferentialGain>0.2</positionZDifferentialGain>
      <positionZIntegralGain>0.0</positionZIntegralGain>
      <positionZLimit>-1</positionZLimit>
      <maxForce>30</maxForce>
      <motionSmallNoise>0.05</motionSmallNoise>
      <motionDriftNoise>0.03</motionDriftNoise>
      <motionDriftNoiseTime>5.0</motionDriftNoiseTime>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- Sensors -->
  <!-- IMU sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name='sensor_imu' type='imu'>
      <always_on> 1 </always_on>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
      <update_rate> 100 </update_rate>
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <plugin name='imu' filename='libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so'>
        <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
      </plugin>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0 </stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0.00 </stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Sonar sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="sonar_link">
    <sensor name="sonar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.02</min>
          <max>10</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="sonar" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=sonar</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/Range</output_type>
        <radiation_type>ultrasound</radiation_type>
        <frame_name>sonar_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="front_cam_link">
    <sensor name="front_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>2.09</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>60</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="camera_front" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_front</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_front_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>front</camera_name>
        <frame_name>front_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- downward looking camera -->
  <gazebo reference="bottom_cam_link">
    <sensor name="down_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>15</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="camera_bottom" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_bottom</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_bottom_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>bottom</camera_name>
        <frame_name>bottom_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

<!-- Gazebo plugin for LiDAR -->
<gazebo reference="lidar_link">
  <sensor type="ray" name="hokuyo_sensor">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
    <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    <ray>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>720</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
          <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
        </horizontal>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.1</min>
        <max>30.0</max>
        <resolution>0.01</resolution>
      </range>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <mean>0.0</mean>
        <stddev>0.01</stddev>
      </noise>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
      <topicName>/drone/lidar</topicName>
      <frameName>lidar_link</frameName>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name="gps" type="gps">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <gps>
        <position_sensing>
          <horizontal>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </vertical>
        </position_sensing>
      </gps>
      <plugin name="gps" filename="libgazebo_ros_gps_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <namespace>/gps</namespace>
          <remapping>~/out:=data</remapping>
        </ros>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>

Here is the URDF:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="sjtu_drone" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.477"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.1152" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1152" iyz="0" izz="0.218"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sjtu_drone_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sjtu_drone_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="sonar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="sonar_link" />
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="sonar_link"/>

  <joint name="front_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="front_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="front_cam_link"/>

  <joint name="bottom_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="bottom_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="bottom_cam_link"/>
  
  <!-- Link for LiDAR sensor -->
  <link name="lidar_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="lidar_visual"> <!-- Added name attribute -->
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="lidar_material"> <!-- Added name attribute -->
        <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <!-- Joint to attach LiDAR to the drone -->
  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 2" rpy="0 0 0"/>  <!-- Adjust the position as needed -->
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="lidar_link"/>
  </joint>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libplugin_drone.so" name="simple_drone">
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <rosNamespace>drone</rosNamespace>
      <imuTopic>imu</imuTopic>
      <rollpitchProportionalGain>10.0</rollpitchProportionalGain>
      <rollpitchDifferentialGain>5.0</rollpitchDifferentialGain>
      <rollpitchLimit>0.5</rollpitchLimit>
      <yawProportionalGain>2.0</yawProportionalGain>
      <yawDifferentialGain>1.0</yawDifferentialGain>
      <yawLimit>1.5</yawLimit>
      <velocityXYProportionalGain>5.0</velocityXYProportionalGain>
      <velocityXYDifferentialGain>2.3</velocityXYDifferentialGain>
      <velocityXYLimit>2</velocityXYLimit>
      <velocityZProportionalGain>5.0</velocityZProportionalGain>
      <velocityZIntegralGain>0.0</velocityZIntegralGain>
      <velocityZDifferentialGain>1.0</velocityZDifferentialGain>
      <velocityZLimit>-1</velocityZLimit>
      <positionXYProportionalGain>1.1</positionXYProportionalGain>
      <positionXYDifferentialGain>0.0</positionXYDifferentialGain>
      <positionXYIntegralGain>0.0</positionXYIntegralGain>
      <positionXYLimit>5</positionXYLimit>
      <positionZProportionalGain>1.0</positionZProportionalGain>
      <positionZDifferentialGain>0.2</positionZDifferentialGain>
      <positionZIntegralGain>0.0</positionZIntegralGain>
      <positionZLimit>-1</positionZLimit>
      <maxForce>30</maxForce>
      <motionSmallNoise>0.05</motionSmallNoise>
      <motionDriftNoise>0.03</motionDriftNoise>
      <motionDriftNoiseTime>5.0</motionDriftNoiseTime>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- Sensors -->
  <!-- IMU sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name="sensor_imu" type="imu">
      <always_on> 1 </always_on>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
      <update_rate> 100 </update_rate>
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu">
        <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
      </plugin>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0 </stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0.00 </stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- Sonar sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="sonar_link">
    <sensor name="sonar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.02</min>
          <max>10</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so" name="sonar">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=sonar</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/Range</output_type>
        <radiation_type>ultrasound</radiation_type>
        <frame_name>sonar_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="front_cam_link">
    <sensor name="front_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>2.09</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>60</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_front">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_front</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_front_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>front</camera_name>
        <frame_name>front_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- downward looking camera -->
  <gazebo reference="bottom_cam_link">
    <sensor name="down_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>15</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_bottom">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_bottom</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_bottom_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>bottom</camera_name>
        <frame_name>bottom_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- Gazebo plugin for LiDAR -->
  <gazebo reference="lidar_link">
    <sensor name="hokuyo_sensor" type="ray">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.1</min>
          <max>30.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so" name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller">
        <topicName>/drone/lidar</topicName>
        <frameName>lidar_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name="gps" type="gps">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <gps>
        <position_sensing>
          <horizontal>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </vertical>
        </position_sensing>
      </gps>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_gps_sensor.so" name="gps">
        <ros>
          <namespace>/gps</namespace>
          <remapping>~/out:=data</remapping>
        </ros>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>



I think the problem is with your lidar plugin, try using this plugin:
<plugin name="robo_scan" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
   <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
   <frame_name>base_scan</frame_name>
</plugin>


thank you it works now!

fatemeh_p can you have a look please on a new question?
